# Slider not showing

Tags: theme, code, magento-ce

Im very new to Magento and programming. My skills are very limited, but i have managed to set up a copy of a website by doing the following.

I made a copy of the SQL database and FTP from this site gooseberrysalon.com/beta/

This has provided me with this gooseberrysalon.com/beta3/ so i can mess around and learn. I started by deleting all the them files which were copied over from /beta and re install the latest ultimo theme, so i could start fresh. However, i cant seem to get the sliders to work on /beta3 as they have done on /beta.

I have check all custom blocks related to the sliders are enabled and that the blocks are located in the infortis settings .Howver, this doesnt work.

One thing i have noticed now is that the source code on beta3 doesn't have the slider code? I think this is the problem?

```
<div class="main-container col1-layout">
    <div class="main-before-top-container"></div>
    <div class="main container">
    <div class="preface grid-full in-col1"> 

    <div class="the-slideshow-wrapper-outer" > 

    <div class="the-slideshow-wrapper"> 

    <div class="the-slideshow slider-arrows2 slider-pagination2 pagination-pos-over-bottom-centered"> 
    <div id="slideshow-e612d07dac853b20eb85a9ffc44d965c" class="slides"> 
    <div class="item slide"> 
    <p><a href="/brand/color-wow.html/"> <img src="/beta/media/wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/slideshow/01.jpg" alt="Color Wow" /></a></p> </div> 
    <div class="item slide"> 
    <p><a href="beta/brand/label-m.html/"> <img src="http://beta/media/wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/slideshow/02.jpg" alt="Lable.m" /></a></p> </div> 
    <div class="item slide"> 
    <p><a href="beta/deliveries/"> <img src="http:/beta/media/wysiwyg/infortis/ultimo/slideshow/03.jpg" alt="Free UK Deliveries on orders over £10" /> </a></p> </div> 
    </div> <!-- end: slides --> 
    </div> <!-- end: the-slideshow --> 


    </div> <!-- end: the-slideshow-wrapper --> 

    </div> <!-- end: the-slideshow-wrapper-outer -->
```

Can anybody help?

Adam

Answer (score 2):

I feel that you might be missing some files when you FTPed everything over. I would suggest migrating over to a version control system so you can verify all the files are correctly in place.

To many things can go wrong by not using a version control system.